# ChartJS Radar Change Label Color

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'd like to style a radar chart using Chart.js, but I can't seem to figure this out.
[image: My Chart]
I'd like to first of all change the color of every text to white, including the title, the label names, and the labels. I'd also like to remove the box around the axis numbers and change their colors to white too. Here is the code I have atm (I use django for the data)

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: {{ subjects|safe }},
        datasets: [{
            label: '2022 Noten',
            data: {{ grades_avg }},
            borderWidth: 1
        }, {
            label: '2021 Noten',
            data: [],
            borderWidth: 0.5
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scale: {
            min: 1,
            max: 6,
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 0.5,
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            r: {
                grid: {
                    color: 'gray'
                },
                angleLines: {
                    color: 'gray'
                },
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Noten im Vergleich'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I just can't wrap my head around this library and I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK. Below I give you an example with useful links to the documentation.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [3.5, 5, 2.5, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    locale: 'en-US',
    scale: {
      min: 1,
      max: 6,
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 0.5,
      }
    },
    scales: {
      r: { // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/
        angleLines: {
          color: 'gray'
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'gray'
        },
        pointLabels: { // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/#point-labels
          color: 'white'
        },
        ticks: { // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/#ticks
          color: 'white',
          backdropColor: 'transparent' // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/_common_ticks.html
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      title: { // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html
        display: true,
        text: 'Title',
        color: 'white'
      },
      legend: {
        labels: { // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration
          color: 'white'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}

canvas {
  background: #282a2d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```